# Why sometimes AWS EC2 works really slow?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, performance

I do only one thing one this server - encoding videos by `ffmpeg`.
And sometimes it does work ok, sometimes it's really slow.

I run the same command just for a test:

```
$ sudo time ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:a copy -vf 'drawbox= : x=0 : y=0 : color=invert : t=2' output1.mp4
ffmpeg version n2.2.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 30 2015 13:20:09 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC) 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)
......
16.24user 0.04system 0:16.30elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 60972maxresident)k
0inputs+6088outputs (0major+15811minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

After 5 hours I run it again, because I saw it starts working slow again.

```
$ sudo time ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:a copy -vf 'drawbox= : x=0 : y=0 : color=invert : t=2' output1.mp4
.......
163.41user 0.84system 2:46.90elapsed 98%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 60988maxresident)k
0inputs+6136outputs (0major+15814minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

As you can see it took 10 times more time than the first time. (1)`16.24user` (2)`163.41user`

Any ideas how can it be fixed?

Comment: What instance type?

Comment: Are you on a micro instance?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I'm testing t2.micro instance.

Comment: @whitesiroi Micro instances, by design, run fast for a while, then **really** slow. You do **not** want to use them for long, CPU intensive tasks like `ffmpeg` runs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

depending on your instance type (burstable cpu instances), you may be dealing with CPU credit.

==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984106/whats-is-cpu-credit-balance-in-ec2

if you find vast fluctuations on a non-burstable instance, you may want to stop and start (not reboot) instance.  this will make the instance come up on a different hypervisor (host box).  it may be the current shared host has issues that will be resolved when launching vm on new host.

Comment: Many thanks, the instance was almost freezing, restart didn't worked, stop/start did the trick!

Comment: @Cassiano Start/Stop worked a treat for me.

Comment: It worked for burstable instance too! :)

Comment: This worked for a Nano I had which had been running very slow for months.

Comment: On Stop and Start the instance, will it erase my existing data?

Answer (score 2):

I use a bunch of EC2 instances; I've also seen wide variance in how long the same job would take to complete - processing the same video again and again.  Sometimes, two runs are very fast, variance less than 1%; other runs the variance is 5 to 10x!  I've noticed that these issues occur more on our smaller instances.  We have a few that are the M*.large or C*.large size and these instances do not have this issue (as much)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looks like problem was in CPU credit, I had 0 at that time.